# ECC error injection on Intel Xeon C5500 platform and issue with unlocking Integrated memory controller registers

Tags: intel, freebsd

I am working on Error Detection module and was attempting to test using the error injection implementation mentioned in Intel® Xeon® Processor C5500/C3500 Series Datasheet, Volume 2  in section 4.12.40. It asks to program the MC_CHANNEL_X_ADDR_MATCH, MC_CHANNEL_X_ECC_ERROR_MASK and MC_CHANNEL_X_ECC_ERROR_MASK registers but attempting to write to this has no effect. Realized there is a lock for this space which is indicated by status in MEMLOCK_STATUS register (device 0: function 0: offset 88h), which in my case is reporting 0x40401 as the set value. This means MEM_CFG_LOCKED is set and I am not able to even unlock using the MC_CFG_CONTROL register (device 0:function 0: offset 90h). I am writing 0x2 to this register but that does not help to unlock the ECC injection registers for writing. How can I achieve this? I am running FreeBSD on the bare metal and not as a virtual machine.

Comment: `4.4.7 MEMLOCK_STATUS`, Bit 0 `MEM_CFG_LOCKED` has for the last sentence of its description the sentence _Can only be changed when in Authenticated Code Mode._ Are you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How does one enable Authenticated Code Mode?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the whole [TXT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Execution_Technology) thing that is necessary for this is not supported on FreeBSD.

But this a quite an arcane area. You might have more luck asking this on the freebsd-hackers mailing list.